# fs vs require JSON

Tags: node.js, fs

I'll start of with saying I'm new to NodeJS but i've been developing in PHP for a number of years (doesn't mean much I know).

I started tinkering with Node recently and discovered something strange I hope someone can help with

I have a file call `local.js` this pulls in a `.JSON` file that is used to setting such as `oAuth keys` and the like.

The initial way I pulled this file in was like:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var settings = fs.readFileSync('./config/settings.json', 'utf8')
```

What I found was that I wouldn't be able to read a value from the `JSON` in `settings` via `settings.key` this would give me `undefined`

Testing out another method below

```
var settings = require('./config/settings.json')
```

Allows me to read the value from the `JSON` via `settings.key`

I was wonder why this is the case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`fs.readFileSync()` just reads the data contained in the file, but it doesn't parse it.

For that, you need an additional step:

```
var settings = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync('./config/settings.json', 'utf8') );
```

Using `require()` *will* parse the data automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response @robertklep I actually had the `JSON.parse` in use at some point before too and I was getting weird errors but maybe that was down to something else. Thanks again :)

Comment: Additionally, with `require` you can omit the `.json` extension and it will cache the file contents, whereas the fs way will re-read the file if you use it multiple times.

Comment: @MattStephens if you see weird errors while `JSON.parse` then it's most likely json schema is broken or you're not supplying string but buffer.

Comment: @VladMiller Actually thinking about it... I think that was an issue with my Constructor to no related.

Comment: @robertklep taking my words and going back school :D

Comment: Intuitively I assume that the require option is more efficient.

How about security? 
Is there any additional dangers of injected code into file when using require to automatically parse it?

Comment: @Lenny using `require()` for JSON files only makes sense for static files (part of a project), not for files that get uploaded (or are otherwise "dynamic" in nature), because the file contents will remain cached in memory by `require`. In that case, the same rules apply as for any `.js` file in a project (make sure they can't be overwritten by malicious code, basically). Still, in such a situation `.json` files are more secure than `.js` files.

Comment: @robertklep yhea thank you. The specific usecase is to have some small persistent state saved on the disk for the case the service dies or becomes restarted.
So it is just written by the service itself ;-).

Still it is always hard to make sure 100% that other malicious code could write something there. So it's interesting to know if also a .json require could be a potential door for injections. For now it seems that functions inside of the .json become ignored.

Comment: @Lenny I think that loading JSON through `require()` is pretty safe (as long as the file has a `.json` extension because `require` uses the extension to determine how to parse the data).

Answer (score 1):

Function `fs.readFileSync()` reads only the contents of file as a string.

While `require()` will read the contents of file as well as parse it using `JSON.parse()` function so you will get a json object in return.

Its better to use `require()` if you are not modifying the json file in between your execution.

Answer (score 0):

`Require` gets all code from the supplied path in the parameter into your variable. In the first case, `require('fs')` is actually shorthand for something like `require('/some/path/fs.js')` and `require.js` stores the code in that path (module) inside your variable. That module contains the `readFileSync` method which, of course, reads the contents of the supplied file into `settings`. Now `require` works just as well with JSON, in the sense that if you `require` a JSON file, `require.js` will parse it and load it inside your variable, and you can use it like a basic js object.